# Question concerning subgroup including center

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p$ be a prime number an $G$ be a group. If $|Z(G)|=p$ then $|G/Z(G)|=p$. This is a direct consequence of the first Isomorphism theorem, isn't it? Since $Z(G)$ is the kernel of the canonical projection.

**Edit.** I think my question breaks down to that I do not fully understand the first part of the last sentence in the proof below.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not true. Using the Isomorphism Theorem on the canonical projection of $G$ onto $G/Z(G)$ gives $|G|/|Z(G)| = |G/Z(G)|$ (domain order over kernel order = image order). In fact, |G/Z(G)| is never prime because G/Z(G) is never non-trivially cyclic but that's a different matter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my question since by your answer I am on the wrong way.

Comment: Re edit: That's what I meant with my last remark, this involves some work. Let's assume for contradiction that $G$ is non-Abelian with $G/Z(G)$ cyclic. Then there exists a non-central $g \in G$ so that $G/Z$ is generated by $gZ$ alone. Now consider an arbitrary $h \in G$ and show using the previous, that $gh=hg$. But then $g$ is in fact central.